# In the ArcGIS Kotlin sample application "Display a Map" where is the ActivityMainBinding class declairation found?

Tags: android, kotlin, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

When I try to duplicate the Esri ArcGIS Kotlin sample project "Display a Map" using their example tutorial. The have you add a private attribute to the MainActivity.kt. I want to know where is the class ActivityMainBinding. It is not in the example code zip file. I'm using ArcGIS Kotlin SDK 200.1.0

```
 private val activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy {
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    }
```

I've search developers.ArcGIS.com and other sources for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This class is automatically generated by the Android Jetpack [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) library. There is no Kotlin or Java source to look at. The source file in this case would be `res/layout/activity_main.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

The ActivityMainBinding class is generated by android studio if you enable data binding in your build.gradle file. See [Android data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).
Your xml view needs to have the root element of layout.